# How to get validation error value(=inputed value, but not in model) angularjs way

Tags: angularjs

I’m trying to get user.name.length value at error message.
If jQuery is used, it is realizable, but isn't there any method unique to Angularjs?

```
<form novalidate name="myForm" ng-submit="addUser()">
<p>Name:
<input type="text" name="name" ng-model="user.name" required ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="8">
<span ng-show="myForm.name.$error.minlength">{{user.name.length}} too short!</span>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you try with `{{myForm.name.$viewValue.length}}`, like below:

```
<input type="text" name="name" ng-model="user.name" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="8" />
                <span ng-show="myForm.name.$error.minlength">{{myForm.name.$viewValue.length}} too short!</span>
                <span ng-show="myForm.name.$error.maxlength">{{myForm.name.$viewValue.length}} too long!</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way ng-minlength and ng-maxlength work, if the input textbox has fewer or more characters than specified by the two directives, then user.name is not populated (I don't even think it is defined).  To see what I mean, add `{{user.name}}` after the <span>.